# SQL CLR Function and import to Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlclr

Is it possible to create a SQL CLR Function, and use in Entity Framework?

I have tried it, and imports with no problem, but when i create a function import to use it, it does not give me the option to select the function.

I'm thinking of this approach because the logic in the function is a complex and would like to share it with sql developers as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a scalar function or a TVF? Are you able to reference other functions of the same type in Entity Framework?

Comment: TVF, not CLR. If i create a sql function it will work fine.

Comment: You meant "not scalar", right? If a T-SQL TVF works but not a SQLCLR TVF, then it probably has to do with not having a discoverable result set that `sp_describe_first_result_set` can see. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Yes, not scalar. SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: `sp_describe_first_result_set` was introduced in SQL Server 2012 so it is probably an issue with `FMTONLY ON`. I can check in an hour or so, but I think this is going to require creating a wrapper T-SQL TVF to SELECT FROM the SQLCLR TVF so that a result set can be determined without actually running the SQLCLR function.

Comment: I just checked `SET FMTONLY ON;` with a SQLCLR TVF and it actually works as expected. So I am not sure why it wouldn't show up for you. Do you have proper SELECT permission on that TVF?

Comment: Interesting.. did you try importing a CLR function to EF and got mapped to a function import?

Comment: No, I did not attempt to use this in EF. I just ran what EF should be using to test / discover such things.